# Upgrading 240v electric heater to mini split AC with heat pump

Tags: electrical, 240v

I currently have a 240V heater that is controlled by a 2 wire thermostat, R and W wires. I understand that I can tie these try together to activate the heater. I plan on using the same wires from the heater to use solely with the new mini split system. Can I tie together the thermostat wires to permanently keep the mini split AC unit is always on? And to be controlled by a remote, of course. Any reason why we should NOT do this? I can rewire to bypass the transformer, but I think I want to save time and avoid going to a crawl space, unscrew the elected box, to wire nut the 3 legs.

Answer (score 1):

That's not how you would combine those two things.

First, a heat pump is reversible.  You bought it for the air conditioning, *but it also heats*.

"Why would I use my heat pump for heat when I already have a perfectly working heater?"  *Because the heater you have now is electric "strip heat", and is dreadfully inefficient.  The heat pump is vastly more efficient.  You will save a fortune using the heat pump as the heater.*

However the heat pump cannot work when it is too cold (we're talking quite cold).

As such, you need a system called "Emergency Heat".  This is commonly electric strip heating, *just like the system you currently have*.

So, you will use a **thermostat designed for heat pumps**.  It will use:

- Heat pump (in cool mode) for cooling
- Heat pump (in heat mode) for heating
- Existing strip heaters for "Emergency Heat" when the heat pump is unable to heat.

The original thermostat is not designed to control a heat pump and blend heat pump heat with emergency heat, and will not be used.

However, since you say the thermostat is already a 24 volt thermostat fed from a transformer, you are "way ahead of the curve".  The 24V controls on your 240V strip heater is already compatible with a heat pump thermostat.

If you are using the thermostat that comes with/on the heat pump, then you will need to follow its instructions for wiring in an external "emergency heat" system.

If you are using an external thermostat, you will need a thermostat cable with many more wires.

Answer (score 0):

In all likelihood you may be able to use the power from the heater to power a mini split. However there are other rules that have to be followed to have a legal installation.

Yes the line voltage thermostat can be jumped so there is always power.
There is a requirement for a disconnect outside at the mini split (this can be put in line with the existing power).
There is also a requirement for a 120v receptacle “within site” or 50’ to service the system.
There are some 100% DIY systems out there that if do not have any leaks are good systems verification of no leaks at the connections is important.

Comment: 50' is a long ways. Maybe 50"?

Comment: Thank you very much.  Now if my mini split unit only requires 115V,  you would change out the breaker or could I just wire nut the unused hot leg?

Comment: If it is 120v you may need to change the breaker, and you will need to adjust the wires so you have a neutral.